# html and CSS - inline images in a container (white background)

Tags: html, css

I want my inline images in a container (white background). My html is:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="award-select">
                    <div class="image-group">
                        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-group">
                        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->
```

My css is:

```
.award-select{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);

  }
```

When I add:

```
.image-group {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    float: left
  }
```

To get my images inline I loose the white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Float or a Height to your award-select class.

```
.award-select{float:left}
.award-select{height:200px;}
```

Your background keeps closing because there is no float on the award-select class but there is one on your other class you need float to be on both.   Adding a height will also solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the ".image-group" divs are set to `float` and the floating divs are not taking any dimension. So your '.award-select' div is 0px by 0px.

**Solution 1:**
You can simply add `height: 100%;` to your '.award-select' div.

```css
.award-select {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  height: 100%;
}

.image-group {
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="award-select">
      <div class="image-group">
        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
      </div>
      <div class="image-group">
        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /row -->
```

**Solution 2:** Since you are using Bootstrap, here is a help class `.clearfix`  you can add to your '.award-select' div to make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, added class="clearfix" to clear the float issue

```
<div class="award-select">
                    <div class="image-group">
                        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image-group">
                        <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                        <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your `CSS`.

Here is the code (run the snippet at the bottom):

```css
.award-select
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
  
.image-group
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="award-select">
            <div class="image-group">
                <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Img" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
            </div>
            <div class="image-group">
                <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Img" src="images/wosmmop.png" />
                <figcaption>Date</figcaption>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /row -->
```